# Empty object returned from gRPC Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, grpc

Basically, the JSON object that's returned from a callback in my gRPC server is empty no matter what I do.

For the most part I'm following [this](https://mherman.org/blog/node-grpc-postgres/) tutorial, except I'm using a SQLite3 server instead of knex, and I've worked to the *listProducts* method. I haven't tried working on the other product methods yet.

---

In *server.js* I get some data from a SQLite3 database, and try to return it in a callback (at the bottom of the method). I also print out the data from the DB to confirm I'm actually getting valid data.

***gRPC server.js***

```
function listProducts(call, callback) {
  console.log("******** Listed the products *********");
  var data = "";

  let db = new sqlite3.Database('../data/testDB.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY, (err) => {
    if(err){
    console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log("connected to DB");
  });

  db.serialize(() => {
    db.get('SELECT NAME as name FROM PEEPS', (err, row) => {
          if(err){
            console.error(err.message);
          }
          console.log(row.name);
          data.name = row.name;
    });
  });

  db.close((err) => {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('closed db');
  });

  callback(null, { products:  data.name });
}
```

**Out put from *gRPC server.js***

```
******** Listed the products *********
connected to DB
Jeff            // Correct data from DB. 
closed db
```

---

The callback returns to *client.js*, where it was called. However, the object is always empty.

If I uncomment *res.json({ name: "jessie" });* and comment *res.json(result);*, the code works as expected; *name: jessie* is sent to the browser as a JSON object.

So that tells me that from the client to the browser the data is being handled correctly. Therefore the problem is when the data is passed from the *server.js* to *client.js*.

***gRPC client.js***

```
// requirements
const path = require('path');
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
const grpc = require('grpc');

// gRPC client
const productProtoPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'protos', 'product.proto');
const productProtoDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(productProtoPath);
const productPackageDefinition = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(productProtoDefinition).product;
const client = new productPackageDefinition.ProductService('localhost:50051', grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

// handlers
const listProducts = (req, res) => {
  client.listProducts({}, (err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
      console.log(typeof result);
      // console.log(res.json(result));
      res.json(result);
      // res.json({ name: "jessie" });
      console.log("*******************");
  });
};
```

**Output from *gRPC client.js***

```
Server listing on port 3000
{}                 //Oh no! An empty JSON object!
object
*******************
```

---

**Edit**
Here is a link to my repository: https://github.com/burke212/grpc-node

Comment: In your server code, it looks like you are setting `data` to an empty string, then passing `data.name` to the callback. You are also initiating some asynchronous actions in between, but you're not waiting for them to finish so they would have no impact on what is being passed to the callback. To see what I mean, try adding a `console.log` right before or after calling the callback.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Thanks for pointing out the empty data string. I tried console.logging before and after the callback, but I received the same result from both; undefined. Maybe that because of hoisting?

Either way I've narrowed down the line of coded that's causing the most trouble; `client.listProducts(...)`. Since its async, the parent call from `fetch` in my index.js returns a `Promise {<state>: "pending"}`. So this leads me to believe I need to make `client.listProducts()` to be sync. Am I on the right track?

Comment: did you try setting this environment variable `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG`? I tried, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that in your server code, your `db` methods are asynchronous but you are trying to access the result synchronously. You need to call the main callback for `listProducts` in the callback for `db.get` to ensure that you have the result of that database request before trying to use it. After making this change your `listProducts` method implementation should look more like this:

```js
function listProducts(call, callback) {

  let db = new sqlite3.Database('../data/testDB.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY);

  db.serialize(() => {
    db.get('SELECT NAME as name FROM PEEPS', (err, row) => {
          if(err){
            console.error(err.message);
          }
          // Call the callback here to use the result of db.get
          callback(null, { products:  row.name });
    });
  });

  db.close();

}
```

For simplicity I omitted the logging. Also, the `sqlite3.Database` constructor and `db.close` do not have callbacks in the example in the `sqlite3` README. I suggest checking again whether those functions actually take callbacks.

In addition to that, now that you have shared the `product.proto` file that defines your service, there is another problem. The `listProducts` method in the `ProductService` service is declared as returning a `ProductList` object. In that message type, the `products` field must be an array of `Product` objects. All of the code in your method implementation is directed towards returning a string in that field, and that does not result in a compatible object.

Comment: Unfortunately, moving the main callback inside `db.get()` doesn’t resolve the issue either. 

To try to break the problem down further, I’ve replaced the body of `listProducts()` with  

    `let data = { products: "jeff" };
    console.log(data);
    callback(null, data);`

just to see if *server.js* will even return a hard coded object.

However, *client.js* is returning an `undefined` value. So the problem therefore is with gRPC then? Have I not setup my .proto correctly?

Comment: If you had included your `.proto` file in the question that would have helped see another problem. You should add that in an edit. Your `listProducts` method is declared as returning a `ProductList` object, but the code you wrote is returning what looks like a `ProductName` object.